# How to decrease number in filename list by sed or similar tool

Tags: file, awk, sed, rename, mv

I have a list of files numbered in the filename, starting eg. at 013 (or another count) but want them renamed to start by 001. I don't mind the tool used (awk, sed, mv, tr, what-ever...)

Example (before -> after):

```
img013.tif -> img001.tif
img014.tif -> img002.tif
...
```

etc.

Appreciate any help. 1000 x thanks,
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a glob expression will retrieve the file list in alphabetical (alphanumerical) order you can simply use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
# The loop iterates over tif files in alphanumerical order
for file in *.tif ; do
    mv -v "$file" "img$(printf "%03d" "$i").tif"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks. OMG, so simple. And I didn't see it yesterday because I tried a "real" rename base on calculation by -12, masking with sed etc...

Comment: Of course it can be only so simple because I assume that the input files appear in a continuous way, like 013, 014, 015,.. , I mean with no gaps. Otherwise you would indeed need to do the math if the gaps need to be preserved.